# How to keep listening to onClick?

Tags: android, button, android-alertdialog

I am currently attempting to create a 'toggle' kind of button, where if a certain boolean is 'true', then it would pop up an AlertDialog, while if false, it would not pop the dialog.

However, the problem is that currently it is only changing the button's behavior when the activity is started, not when the boolean is actually changed.

I think this is because I've put the method is in onStart, though I am not quite sure where to put the code.

How do I keep listening to the onClick so that the button changes as soon as the user changes the settings?

The below is my current code:

```
public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        final SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        final Button StopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.StopButton);
        boolean RequestingLU = settings.getBoolean("RequestingLU", true);
        if (RequestingLU) {
            StopButton.setText(R.string.Stop_Button);
            StopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder StopDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainMenu.this);
                    StopDialog.setTitle(R.string.Stop_Title);
                    StopDialog.setMessage(R.string.Stop_Message);
                    StopDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.Stop_Button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            editor.putBoolean("RequestingLU", false);
                            editor.apply();
                            Toast.makeText(MainMenu.this, "You have stopped the app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    StopDialog.setNeutralButton(R.string.Negative_Button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            //Closes box
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    StopDialog.create().show();
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            StopButton.setText(R.string.Start_Button);
            StopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    editor.putBoolean("RequestingLU", true);
                    editor.apply();
                    Toast.makeText(MainMenu.this, "You have started the app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }

    }
```

Comment: try it in onResume/onCreate

Comment: onResume? Is the onResume called when the AlertDialog is closed?

Comment: make it in oncreate

Answer (score 1):

You may try like below:

```
    if (RequestingLU) {
        StopButton.setText(R.string.Stop_Button);
    } else {
        StopButton.setText(R.string.Start_Button); 
    }

    StopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String startText = getResources().getString(R.string.Start_Button);
            String stopText = getResources().getString(R.string.Stop_Button);

            String buttonText = StopButton.getText().toString();

            if(stopText.equals(buttonText)){
                AlertDialog.Builder StopDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainMenu.this);
                StopDialog.setTitle(R.string.Stop_Title);
                StopDialog.setMessage(R.string.Stop_Message);
                StopDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.Stop_Button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        editor.putBoolean("RequestingLU", false);
                        editor.apply();
                        Toast.makeText(MainMenu.this, "You have stopped the app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        StopButton.setText(R.string.Start_Button);
                    }
                });
                StopDialog.setNeutralButton(R.string.Negative_Button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //Closes box
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                StopDialog.create().show();
            } else if(startText.equals(buttonText)){
                editor.putBoolean("RequestingLU", true);
                editor.apply();
                Toast.makeText(MainMenu.this, "You have started the app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                StopButton.setText(R.string.Stop_Button);
            }
        }
    });
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: after your `boolean RequestingLU = settings.getBoolean("RequestingLU", true);` line

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct approach is to declare it inside `onCreate()`.

After taking a short look into your code, I can't see where you declare your `RequestingLU` boolean to `true`.

You need to declare as follows:

```
StopDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.Stop_Button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

 @Override
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

    editor.putBoolean("RequestingLU", true);
    editor.apply();

    dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });

StopDialog.setNeutralButton(R.string.Negative_Button, new    DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

     editor.putBoolean("RequestingLU", false);
     editor.apply();
     //Closes box
     dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
```

Answer (score -1):

Okay, I found the solution.

I just move the entire code block into an onClickListener.
That is, put the boolean RequestingLU check inside the onClickListener instead of the other way around.

Full code here:

```
final SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        final Button StopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.StopButton);
        StopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                boolean RequestingLU = settings.getBoolean("RequestingLU", true);
                if (RequestingLU) {
                    StopButton.setText(R.string.Start_Button);
                    AlertDialog.Builder StopDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainMenu.this);
                    StopDialog.setTitle(R.string.Stop_Title);
                    StopDialog.setMessage(R.string.Stop_Message);
                    StopDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.Stop_Button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            editor.putBoolean("RequestingLU", false);
                            editor.apply();
                            Toast.makeText(MainMenu.this, "You have stopped the app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    StopDialog.setNeutralButton(R.string.Negative_Button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            //Closes box
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    StopDialog.create().show();
                }
                else {
                    StopButton.setText(R.string.Stop_Button);
                    editor.putBoolean("RequestingLU", true);
                    editor.apply();
                    Toast.makeText(MainMenu.this, "You have started the app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```